# ascending order by a.bill_id id in array_merge in codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql, sorting, codeigniter

```
$this->db->select('b.name as user_name,a.bill_id,a.dat,a.bill_id,a.buyer_typ');    
$this->db->from('tra_books_sales_head a'); 
$this->db->join('mas_staff_head b','b.staff_id = a.staff_id');  
$query1 = $this->db->get()->result();

$this->db->select('a.customer_name as user_name,a.bill_id,a.dat,b.bill_id,a.buyer_typ'); 
$this->db->distinct();          
$this->db->from('tra_books_sales_head a');
$this->db->join('tra_books_sales_dt b','b.bill_id = a.bill_id');
$this->db->where('a.customer_name is not NULL');       
$query2 = $this->db->get()->result();
return $query =array_merge($query1,$query2);
```

How can I get ascending order above this query?

`order by a.bill_id`

Comment: This is an XY Problem but I don't have the sample data to be able to confidently offer a refactor of your 2-query approach.  You should be only making 1 trip to the database and using CodeIgniter's `order_by()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$this->db->order_by();`. Try:
`$this->db->order_by('a.bill_id','asc');`

If you want to order elements after array_merge you should use `array_multisort`, you can read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)